# Dart: How would I run a while loop only while the program is awaiting a value from a function?

Tags: dart, asynchronous

```dart
void main() async {
  print("Function Starting");
  // I want a while loop here and break once the function has completed.
  print(await myFunction());
}

Future<String> myFunction() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => "Function completed");
}
```

I would basically like to have the program blink "contacting server" while its waiting for the function to finish.

Thank you all :)

Comment: Why do you want a while loop to keep running? Instead, you can create a `Timer.periodic` which does what you want and you can then cancel this timer when your operation are done.

Comment: I am trying this now but not entirely sure how i would implement this, to work along side waiting for my function to complete? Would you mind showing me an example please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That'd be a standard use for a FutureBuilder.  Just take any of the dozens of examples that use CircularProgressIndicator and put a blinking message in there instead.

Comment: Question does not state if they are using Flutter, which your suggested solution require.

Comment: Yep just trying to learn dart in more detail experimenting with async programming. I have done it using flutter with your solution. But thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void main() async {
  bool hasFinished = false;
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), (timer) {
    if (hasFinished == true) {
      timer.cancel();
    } else {
      print("Please wait, we are contacting the server...\n");
    }
  });
  hasFinished = await myFunction();
  print("Connected to server");
}

Future<bool> myFunction() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => true);
}
```

Thank you julemand101 that was exactly what i was looking for. Managed to get it working.

Comment: I would recommend just saving a reference to `Timer.periodic` and then call `cancel()` on that when needed. Instead of introducing your own boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution for a graphical UI is Flutter and a FutureBuilder.

But if you want plain Dart in a Console:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  print("Function Starting");
  
  final blinkWhileWaiting = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) => print("blink"));
  
  final result = await myFunction();
  
  blinkWhileWaiting.cancel();
  
  // I want a while loop here and break once the function has completed.
  print(result);
}

Future<String> myFunction() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => "Function completed");
}
```